# How to limit the default cache

Tags: php, symfony

How can I limit the default cache in symfony 2? Right now it can increase so much that it overflows the server's capacity.

Is there some simple way to do this, maybe some setting in configuration file? I couldn't find the info about it anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: If you limit the size of the cache you will lose its benefits. If a page is not in the cache Symfony2 will have to create the cache or work without cache for every request.

Answer (score 0):

Here you found anything you want to know about "cache control". If you still have any problem the you can ask.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html

Comment: Please don't just post link-only answers. Add some content to your post that would explain how to solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @Niladri Mukharjee: I don't see how to limit the size of the cache on this page.